# NullPointer Warning for ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cxf

I have a Spring Boot Apache CXF web application.  It is running just fine.  However whenever I close down the application I get a warning about a nullpointer from the ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent.  It looks like it might be related to the Apache CXF bus.

```
11:10:24.728 INFO  [Thread-10][AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext] Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@39b667c3: startup date [Thu May 11 11:09:48 PDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
11:10:24.738 WARN  [Thread-10][AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext] Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.replaceNode(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1106)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1097)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.DestinationRegistryImpl.removeDestination(DestinationRegistryImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.deactivate(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:961)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractObservable.setMessageObserver(AbstractObservable.java:65)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.stop(ServerImpl.java:174)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.destroy(ServerImpl.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.ServerRegistryImpl.preShutdown(ServerRegistryImpl.java:90)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.CXFBusLifeCycleManager.preShutdown(CXFBusLifeCycleManager.java:97)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.shutdown(ExtensionManagerBus.java:326)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.shutdown(ExtensionManagerBus.java:313)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus.onApplicationEvent(SpringBus.java:109)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus$1.onApplicationEvent(SpringBus.java:58)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:382)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:336)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:989)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$2.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:923)
11:10:24.780 INFO  [Thread-10][AnnotationMBeanExporter] Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Here is a class I wrote that I think the error may be stemming from, but I am not sure.

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;


@Configuration
public class EndpointConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;

    @Autowired
    private AmazonS3 s3client;

    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
      EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus,
            new AcmeWebServiceImpl(s3client));
      endpoint.publish();
      return endpoint;
  }

  @Bean 
  public AmazonS3 amazonS3(){
     AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
     return amazonS3;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same problem with a Spring Boot Apache CXF web application that is giving me the same error when it shuts down...I am trying to find a solution for a few days now...I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: @CrengutaS I have not found an answer yet. Did you? I am going to dive back into this project in the near future and I'll update this post with my findings.

Comment: we managed to find a workaround and get rid of the NPE within 3 days of trying to figure it out...I posted the whole story as an answer... it's quite lengthy, I apologise for that.

Answer (score 5):

I am posting this as an answer, maybe it helps someone else also.

Yes, I did manage to fix it … after 3 days of trying … it’s more like a workaround, maybe fix is too much to say, since the fix should be probably done in the cxf code… Actually our stack trace was a little different, I am attaching it below. Similar until a certain point, so maybe how we fixed it could be of some help to you. Here it is:

[image]

What we noticed was that in *DestinationRegistryImpl*- *removeDestination* method, line #63, the path that was being removed from the *ConcurrentHashmap* was null and this came from one level up *AbstractHTTPDestination.deactivate(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:965)*. In our case we used an instance of *ServletDestination* (a child of *AbstractHTTPDestination*) which inherited the protected variable *path* and had this variable set through its constructor(ServletDestination constructor) in org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestinationFactory - #33, where the address of the EndpointInfo instance was being set as the path. 
All we had to do is set an address to our endpoint(JAXRSServerFactoryBean) and this translated as the path not being null anymore and we got rid of the NPE.

I am sorry for the legth of it, hope it makes some sense…we had 3 full days of debugging anf looking through the code of the cxf framework and that was not very nice..

We added line 74 and got rid of the NPE:

[image]

Comment: This solved my issue; thanks for sharing! I've actually been dealing with this issue for a while, just haven't had the time to research it given its annoying but non-critical behavior.